# how to get controller method name in Spring Interceptor preHandle method

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations, interceptor

In my application based on spring mvc and spring security I am using `@Controller` annotation to configure controller.

I have configured **Spring Handler Interceptor** and in `preHandle()` method , I want to get method name which is going to be call by interceptor.

I want to get custom annotation defined on controller method in `preHandle()` method of `HandlerInterceptor` so that I can manage by logging activity for that particular method.

Please have a look at my application requirement and code

```
@Controller
public class ConsoleUserManagementController{
@RequestMapping(value = CONSOLE_NAMESPACE + "/account/changePassword.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@doLog(true)
public ModelAndView showChangePasswordPage() {
    String returnView = USERMANAGEMENT_NAMESPACE + "/account/ChangePassword";
    ModelAndView mavChangePassword = new ModelAndView(returnView);
    LogUtils.logInfo("Getting Change Password service prerequisit attributes");
    mavChangePassword.getModelMap().put("passwordModel", new PasswordModel());
    return mavChangePassword;
}
}
```

---

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
   // here I want the controller method name(i.e showChangePasswordPage() 
   // for /account/changePassword.do url ) to be called and that method annotation 
   // (i.e doLog() ) so that by viewing annotation , I can manage whether for that 
   // particular controller method, whether to enable logging or not.
}
```

I am using SPRING 3.0 in my application

Comment: Did you check doing it the following way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about the Handler interceptor, but you could try to use Aspects and create a general interceptor for all your controller methods.

Using aspects, it would be easy to access your joinpoint method name.

You can inject the request object inside your aspect or use:

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

To retrieve it from your advice method.

For instance:

```
@Around("execution (* com.yourpackages.controllers.*.*(..)) && @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
public Object doSomething(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp){
 pjp.getSignature().getDeclaringType().getName();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bob, but I want to try first Handler Interceptor , if it is not helpful. then I can decide to implement Aspect,

Comment: Yes Bob, finally I have replaced Handler Interceptor by Aspect

Comment: @Vinicius Carvalho - Did you get the solution if I really don't wanted to use the Aspect ?