# Spring MVC Controller classname from JSP / page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a question, and a problem that I need fixed soon... I have pulled my hair out while going through some alternatives on how to solve this problem.

See, I have a need to display the current serving Spring Controller from a JSP page. The name doesn't have to be parsed in the JSP itself, I'm actually using another class (a kind of taglibrary) to display this information on the bottom of ever page.

Is there a way to get the controller name from an outside class? (When i say outside, I mean from another class than the Controller itself.)
Perhaps from the request somehow? (Or some Spring Security request attribute?).
Perhaps an interceptor?

I would like to avoid extending a class from the controller just to fix this issue.

Any advice is appriciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show all controllers and mappings in a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766800/how-to-show-all-controllers-and-mappings-in-a-view)

Comment: By currently serving controller, do you mean the one which just processed the request and presented the currently loaded view.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get name of Spring controller and method in view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169722/spring-3-web-mvc-get-name-of-controller-and-method-in-view)

Comment: @Pratik Yes, exactly. And I'd like to get that information from outside the controller itself. I don't want to edit a bunch of controllers just to get this to work, I'd like to get this working from perhaps an interceptor, or an outside class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement a [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html)*** it has a method `postHandle`, that has the two parameters you need:

- `Object handler` - that the can be cast to `HandlerMethod`, contains the information about the Controller Method that has handled the request
- `ModelAndView` - there you need to add the new information about the handling Method

complete Method signature `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor#postHandle`:

```
void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response,
                Object handler,
                ModelAndView modelAndView)
      throws Exception;
```

** Instead of implementing a `HandlerInterceptor` directly, one can extend `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` - that is a convenient abstract class that implements all methods of `HandlerInterceptor` with an empty body, so that one only need to override the methods that are needed.*

** Don't get confused, there are two `HandlerInterceptor` classes, one for Servlets, and one for Portlets (`org.springframework.web.portlet.HandlerInterceptor`). Use the `HandlerInterceptor` for Servlets `oorg.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor` !*

Comment: To clearify how this solved me problem. First, I cast `handler` to an `HandlerMethod`, then get the classname from `handlerMethod.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getName()`, and set it as a request attribute, which I then can use in my custom taglib.

Answer (score 1):

The normal java way, from mwithin the controller itself probably won;t work as spring creates a proxy of the original class :

```
String className = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

I think you need to implement a [request mapping handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766800/how-to-show-all-controllers-and-mappings-in-a-view)

Comment: This requires me to edit a BUNCH of controllers. I was more thinking of getting it to work globally by using an interceptor or such

Comment: @RobinJonsson the RequestMappingHandlerMapping doesn't require editing the existing controllers

Answer (score 0):

You can create a after advise interceptor which will be called after your controller is called. In this interceptor you can get hold of the pointCut method on which this advice was applied. Once you have that you can add it as a property in ModelAndView map.