# In a Spring-mvc interceptor, how can I access to the handler controller method?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, interceptor

In a Spring-mvc interceptor I want to access to the handler controller method

```
public class CustomInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor  {
    public boolean preHandle(
        HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, 
            Object handler) {

        log.info(handler.getClass().getName()); //access to the controller class
        //I want to have the controller method
        ...
        return true;
   }
   ...
}
```

I have found :

[how-to-get-controller-method-name-in-spring-interceptor-prehandle-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384903/how-to-get-controller-method-name-in-spring-interceptor-prehandle-method)

But it only work around. I want the method name to access to the annotation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can cast the `Object handler` to `HandlerMethod`.

```
HandlerMethod method = (HandlerMethod) handler;
```

Note however that the `handler` argument passed to `preHandle` is not always a `HandlerMethod` (careful with `ClassCastException`). `HandlerMethod` then has methods you can use to get annotations, etc.

Comment: @Reimeus Absolutely, unless you know you only have handler methods. For example, if the app only has `@Controller` to handle requests, then you're guaranteed to only have `HandlerMethod` instances.

Answer (score 12):

HandlerInterceptors will only provide you access to the HandlerMethod IF you have registered your interceptors like so :

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class InterceptorRegistry extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new InternalAccessInterceptor());
        registry.addInterceptor(new AuthorizationInterceptor());
    }

}
```

In all other cases, the handler object will point to the controller. Most documentation on the web seemed to have missed this subtle point.

Comment: But why is this so? Could you provide some information why it doesn't work when declaring it inside the spring.xml with ``<mvc:interceptors><bean .. >``