# Unable to Extend spring controller class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This is my controller class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class TokenEndpointspring extends SuperController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/springtokenclientid")

    public @ResponseBody
    OAuthParams authorizeClientIdSecret(
            @RequestParam("param1") String param1,
            @RequestParam("param2") String param2, HttpServletRequest req)
            throws OAuthSystemException, IOException {
        OAuthParams param = new OAuthParams();
        if (CheckClientid(param1,param2)) {
            param.setHaserror(false);
        } else {
            param.setHaserror(true);
            param.setErrorMessage("invlaid client id ");

        }

        return param;
    }
```

This is my super controller class.This class is intended to be extended by every controller

```
public class SuperController   {


    public boolean CheckCommonParameter(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
        // some logic 
    }
```

This is my interceptor

```
public class Interceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    // class cast exception is thrown 
        SuperController supercontroller=(SuperController)handler;

        // this is what i want to achieve 
        if(!supercontroller.CheckCommonParameter(request, response){
return false;
        }
```

**I am unable to cast handler object to SuperController object.**

**I am getting class cast exception.**

When i checked with code for super class

```
handler.getClass().getSuperclass().newInstance();
```

**It is returning instance of Object Class but not my super class SuperController.**

**Do i have to make extra configuration for it ?Is it possible to achieve it in spring mvc ?**

Comment: Did you attempt to debug this at all and find out what type that object is?

Comment: When debugging i am getting TokenEndpointspring  object.When again debugging with code handler.getClass().getSuperclass().newInstance();  i am not getting SuperController as super class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Spring MVC 3.1+,  handler is **not** an instance of the Controller that handles the requests. It is an instance of `HandlerMethod`. Check out [this](http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2012/02/spring-mvc-31-handlermethod.html) blog post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17575688/2504224) SO answer

Answer (score 1):

If you like to check some parameters on each request take a look at the annotation

```
@ControllerAdvice
```

You basically define one class with this annotation and it will be called at each request. There you can define model attribute methods, error handler methods and so on.

You could create a method producing a modelattribute "_valid" with you requestparams as input, and throw an exception if its not valid. Then an exceptionhandler method can catch that and produce an error page.