# Spring HandlerInterceptor: how to access class annotations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I registered my interceptor with the following code

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
 ...
 @Override
 public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor( myInterceptor() );
 }
 ...
}
```

Here the interceptor definition

```
public class MyInterceptorimplements HandlerInterceptor {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    // Check to see if the handling controller is annotated
    for (Annotation annotation : Arrays.asList(handler.getClass().getDeclaredAnnotations())){
        if (annotation instanceof MyAnnotation){
            ... do something
```

However the handler.getClass().getDeclaredAnnotations() is not returning the class level annotations of the Controller intercepted.

I can only get the method level annotations which is not what I want in this case.

The same interceptor works fine with xml configuration (using Spring 3):

```
<bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="myInterceptor"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Is there a way to have class level information in Spring 4?

According to 
[In a Spring-mvc interceptor, how can I access to the handler controller method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575623/in-a-spring-mvc-interceptor-how-can-i-access-to-the-handler-controller-method)
"HandlerInterceptors will only provide you access to the HandlerMethod" using the configuration above. But what is the alternative configuration to get class level information?

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges. The `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` is old and deprecated newer versions (including the java config) use the `RequestMethodHandlerMapping` using that in XML would lead you to the same result (if you want to compare apples with apples). As stated you get an object of the type `HandlerMethod` use the `getBean` method of that class to get the actual object executing your request. Or use `getMethod` to get the selected method.

Comment: @selvinsource Are you sure the `handler` object is of the type you think it is? It may be a proxy object, and therefore `getDeclaredAnnotations` may not work on it.

Comment: thanks to both for your inputs, I found the solution: ((HandlerMethod)handler).getBean().getClass().getDeclaredAnnotations())

Answer (score 18):

You can access spring controller class level annotations in the interceptor using handler method.
But you have to be aware that the Casting to HandlerMethod might throw an exception because no Method was found (404)

```java
 @Override
 public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
  System.out.println("Pre-handle");
  HandlerMethod hm;
  try {
   hm = (HandlerMethod) handler;
  } catch (ClassCastException e) {
   return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
  }
  Method method = hm.getMethod();
  // Sometimes Controller.class wont work and you have to use RestController.class just depends on what you use.
  if (method.getDeclaringClass().isAnnotationPresent(Controller.class)) {
   if (method.isAnnotationPresent(ApplicationAudit.class)) {
    System.out.println(method.getAnnotation(ApplicationAudit.class).value());
    request.setAttribute("STARTTIME", System.currentTimemillis());
   }
  }
  return true;
 }
```