# Can I determine in a servlet filter whether a HttpServletRequest maps to a particular Spring controller class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

I'm working on an application that's using a [`OncePerRequestFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html) to do some custom log-like behavior using the incoming web request.  This behavior uses both the `HttpServletRequest` & `HttpServletResponse`.  Additionally, the filter uses both [`ContentCachingRequestWrapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ContentCachingRequestWrapper.html) & [`ContentCachingResponseWrapper`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/ContentCachingResponseWrapper.html) to access the request/response bodies.

It's been decided that we only want to do this behavior when methods in particular Spring controllers have been called, since it's not something we want to do for other controllers/actuator endpoints/etc.  Is there a way to tell whether the incoming request will be (or was) mapped to a controller?

```java
public class ExampleFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Can I tell here whether this will be mapping to an endpoint in
        // ExampleController or NestedExampleController?

        ContentCachingRequestWrapper requestToUse = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseToUse = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);

        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(requestToUse, responseToUse);

            // Can I tell here whether this was mapped to an endpoint in
            // ExampleController or OtherExampleController?
        } finally {
            responseToUse.copyBodyToResponse(); // Write the cached body back to the real response
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/example")
public class ExampleController {
  @GetMapping("/{id}")
  public Example retrieveExample() {
    return getValue(); // Retrieve the value
  }

  // ...
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/example/{id}/nested")
public class NestedExampleController {
  @GetMapping("/{nestedId}")
  public NestedExample retrieveNestedExample() {
    return getValue(); // Retrieve the value
  }

  // ...
}
```

I've dug around the Spring MVC/Boot internals a bit, and I'm not sure if there's a way to easily do this.  As an alternative, I can do some manual URL pattern matching, which probably won't necessarily exactly match up to the methods in the controllers, but may get me close enough to be an acceptable solution.

To summarize: is there a way in a web filter to tell whether the incoming request will be mapped to a controller (prior to executing the filter chain) or whether it was mapped to a controller (after executing the filter chain)?

Comment: Does it have to be only specific controller classes? Specific methods in said `@Controller` classes? From the wording, this sounds like it would be easily solvable using AOP and an aspect + pointcut for that specific class (or matching methods, if you need it more specific).

Comment: Specific classes is all I need.

Comment: Then AOP should suit your needs just fine, especially since all you want to do is log - one of the most common use-cases. I'll write up an answer in a few minutes if you'd like.

Comment: You can also get the class via a `HandlerInterceptor`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352320/get-request-mapping-object-in-spring-interceptor-to-get-actual-url-string-patte/51352820#51352820 not your exact request but can use it to tell class/methods that the request is mapped to

Comment: @DarrenForsythe That looks promising.  I'll take a look.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe Looks like that won't work since I'm wrapping the request & response with `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` & `ContentCachingResponseWrapper`, which is something `HandlerInterceptor` explicitly doesn't let you do.  "Filters are more powerful, for example they allow for exchanging the request and response objects that are handed down the chain."  I've updated the question to make that clear.

Comment: A filter is executed way before the request dispatching takes place, so the simple answer is no you cannot. You could do this easily with a `HandlerInterceptor`. What you could do is use the `HandlerInterceptor` for the logging together with a filter that will wrap the request/response in the `ContentCachgin*Wrapper`. That way you can do both. Else you would need to go into the internals of all configured `HandlerMapping`s available in the context, fire it of and see if there is a match. So you could do it, but the request mapping would be done twice and would thus affects performance impact.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is basically a [cross-cutting concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern) that targets a specific part of your application - in this case, logging.

This is one of the most common use-cases for aspect-oriented programming, for which Spring has built-in support using AspectJ-style pointcuts.

You will need:

1. To enable AOP within your Spring configuration on a configuration class, as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AopConfiguration {
}
```

2. Define an aspect, e.g. as follows:

```java
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {

    Logger log = ...; // define logger

    // Matches all executions in com.example.ExampleController,
    // with any return value, using any parameters   
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.example.ExampleController.*(..))")
    public void controllerExecutionPointcut() {}

    @Around("controllerExecutionPointcut()")
    public Object aroundTargetControllerInvocation(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
    
        log.debug("About to invoke method: {}", pjp.getSignature().getName());
        
        try {
            return pjp.proceed(); 
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // note that getArgs() returns an Object[],
            // so you may want to map it to a more readable format
            log.debug("Encountered exception while invoking method with args {}", pjp.getArgs());
            throw t;
        }
        
        log.debug("Sucessfully finished invocation");
    }
}
```

See e.g. [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-pointcut-tutorial) guide to learn more about pointcut expressions.

Another common use-case for this is timing your method calls, although for that something like Micrometer (and the Micrometer adapter for Spring) using `@Timed` would probably be better.

You may also wish to read through the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop), which devotes quite a lot of information on how AOP in Spring works.

*Note*: as will almost all other Spring proxying mechanisms, invocations from within the target object will *not* be proxied, i.e. `this.otherControllerMethod()` will not be subject to interception by the above advice. Similarly, `private` methods also cannot be intercepted. See section [5.4.3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-pointcuts) of the reference documentation for more information.

As a last note, if performance is of great importance, you should check out AspectJ compile-time or load-time weaving, which gets rid of some of the overhead introduced by Spring's proxying mechanism (which is what Spring AOP uses under the hood). This will most likely not be necessary in your case, but is good to keep in mind.

---

Edit for comment:

> Thanks! One caveat with this approach is that it does not give me access to the HttpServletRequest or HttpServletResponse, which is something I'm making use of. I can see where this would be helpful if that wasn't something I needed. I see that I wasn't explicit about that requirement in my question, so I'll update accordingly.

Indeed, that is unfortunately not directly possible with this approach. If you really need the request, then the `HandlerInterceptor` approach mentioned by @DarrenForsythe is another possible to go. If all you're going for is logging though, I see no reason why you absolutely need the request - unless you wish to extract specific headers and log those.

In that case, IMO, a `OncePerRequestFilter` as you originally tried would be far better, as you can control for which requests the filter gets applied (using `shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request)` and matching on the URL).

Comment: Thanks!  One caveat with this approach is that it does not give me access to the `HttpServletRequest` or `HttpServletResponse`, which is something I'm making use of.  I can see where this would be helpful if that wasn't something I needed.  I see that I wasn't explicit about that requirement in my question, so I'll update accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, it's extracting specific information from the request and response (URL, response status, request/response body using a wrapped servlet request/response, etc.), which neither the pointcut nor `HandlerInterceptor` allow for.

Comment: I see. In that case, using a filter will most likely be the most practical approach.

Answer (score 1):

After some additional poking around and some trial and error, I discovered that the controller is accessible through the [`RequestMappingHandlerMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html) bean.  When the request can be handled by a controller, this will map the request to a [`HandlerMethod`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/HandlerMethod.html) for the controller's request handling method.

```java
public class ExampleFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Object handler = getHandlerBean(request);
        boolean isHandledController = handler instanceof ExampleController
                || handler instanceof NestedEampleController;

        if (!isHandledController) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        // ...
    }

    private Object getHandlerBean(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            HandlerExecutionChain handlerChain = requestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandler(request);
            if (handlerChain != null) {
                Object handler = handlerChain.getHandler();
                if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
                    return ((HandlerMethod) handler).getBean();
                }
            }
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void initFilterBean() {
        WebApplicationContext appContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
        requestMappingHandlerMapping = appContext.getBean(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.class);
    }
}
```

To be extra thorough and truly mimic Spring's handler logic, the [`DispatcherServlet`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html) logic could be used/mimicked instead of directly referencing `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`.  This will consult all handlers, not just the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`.

```java
public class ExampleFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Object handler = getHandlerBean(request);
        boolean isHandledController = handler instanceof ExampleController
                || handler instanceof NestedEampleController;

        if (!isHandledController) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        // ...
    }

    private Object getHandlerBean(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {
            HandlerExecutionChain handlerChain = getHandler(request);
            if (handlerChain != null) {
                Object handler = handlerChain.getHandler();
                if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
                    return ((HandlerMethod) handler).getBean();
                }
            }
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Duplicates the protected "getHandler" method logic from DispatcherServlet.
     */
    private HandlerExecutionChain getHandler(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        List<HandlerMapping> handlerMappings = dispatcherServlet.getHandlerMappings();
        if (handlerMappings != null) {
            for (HandlerMapping mapping : handlerMappings) {
                HandlerExecutionChain handler = mapping.getHandler(request);
                if (handler != null) {
                    return handler;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initFilterBean() {
        WebApplicationContext appContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
        dispatcherServlet = appContext.getBean(DispatcherServlet.class);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if there is a more idiomatic approach, and it definitely feels like it's jumping through some hoops and digging into the Spring internals a bit too much.  But it does appear to work, at least on spring-web 5.2.7.RELEASE.

Comment: Will it work, yes partially as there might be more `HandlerMapping`s available which all need to be consulted. Will it return a match it will, however it comes with a performance impact as each request is now mapped twice (once in your filter and the other by the `DispatcherServlet`). So yes it might work but it can have quite an impact on your throughput. Hence the suggestion of the `Filter` for wrapping the request and the `HandlerInterceptor` for the logging. No additional overhead for the mapping and you get which handler is invoked.

Comment: @M.Deinum Makes sense.  I may take a look into that approach as well.  Thanks!

Comment: @M.Deinum Addressed the issue of consulting all `HandlerMapping`s by consulting the `DispatcherServlet` rather than `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`.