# Why is a GET request mapped to "/error" in Spring-Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, request-mapping

When I send a GET request to `/todo-list/user/list`
it was mapped to `/error`.

#### Code

Interceptor:

```java
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;

    RequestMapping classMapping = handlerMethod.getMethod().getDeclaringClass().getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
    // when debugging: classMapping.value() was "${server.error.path:${error.path:/error}}"
    RequestMapping methodMapping = handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);

    //some other codes
```

Controller:

```java
//the contexPath is "/todo-list"
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserController
```

Method

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/list")
public @ResponseBody Page<UserProjection> listGrid() {
    return userService.listGrid();
}
```

I checked the address and method and whatever I think is the reason.
When debugging my code, `classMapping.value()` was equal to `"${server.error.path:${error.path:/error}}"`.

What is the problem?

Comment: Did the GET request redirect to `/error` page when testing? Can you post the the full HTTP-response of the test-request. What did you expect to see for `classMapping.value()` ? What happens when you get the value for the *present annotation* which is `GetMapping` not `RequestMapping` - like [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352320/get-request-mapping-object-in-spring-interceptor-to-get-actual-url-string-patte) ?

Comment: this is inside the authorization interceptor and the response is a 401 Unauthorized, with no redirecting. I was expecting '/user', as other methods in this controller are mapping correctly.